# regular expression // want to find a between custom token with all characters

Tags: regex

I want to find all characters between MyCustomToken.

For example, If MyCustomToken is `@@`:

```
@@abcdefghijk@@       -> regex: (@@)(.*)(@@)     ->  result: abcdefghijk
```

But I want to get all characters with line feed and white space.

This does not work:

```
(@@)(.\*\s)*(@@)
```

Comment: Use [`@@((?:.|\s)*?)@@`](https://regex101.com/r/zRtn4T/1), or `@@(.*?)@@` with dot-all flag.

Comment: wow greak!! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept! ;)